# Remove CUSTOM_RINGTONE from contact or revert it to default ringtone in android

Tags: android

i know how to assign custom contact ringtone and also how to assign phone ringtone programmatically . but my requirement is to remove custom ringtone assigned to a particular contact OR set it to default ringtone.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,contactID);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.putNull(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE);
    getContentResolver().update(contactUri, values, null, null);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.